# The provided database edition "" is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm getting "The provided database edition "" is not valid." error, when importing a database using the azure api.

I'm using the endpoint from the documentation: [Import to a new database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/databases/import-database#imports-to-a-new-database).

Im getting a 202 which means it is processing the request. When I check the import/export history tab in the sql server azure portal, I see that import failed with the mentioned error.

Important:

- If I import to a empty database using this endpont [Import to existing DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/databases/import#imports-to-an-existing-empty-database.), it works
- When I do this process from the azure portal, the import works

Looks like the error only happens when importing to a new database

Comment: That is not Azure API Management, Azure API Management is a seprate azure product than Azure SQL. So basically you are having issue with the management apis of the azure sql service.

Answer (score 0):

***We should Set valid azure DB Edition for api***

ImportNewDatabaseDefinition(StorageKeyType.StorageAccessKey, bacpacSettings.StorageKey,
new Uri(bacpacSettings.BacpacUrl), azureInfraSettings.SqlServer.AdminUser,
azureInfraSettings.SqlServer.AdminPassword)
{
DatabaseName = databaseNamePrefix + projectId,
Edition ="Standard"//Set valid azure DB Edition here
},

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.sql.models.databaseimportdefinition?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserverserviceobjective?view=azps-8.3.0